# Highcharts resetZoom xy after klickin on a rangeSelector

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to reset the choosen xy zoomvalue after klickin on a rangeSelector (e.g. 1y), because the chart looks distorted when I am switching from xy zoomvalue to a specific range.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is how Highstock works, see [this thread](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/979).

What come cross my mind is to disable range selector and use your own button which will reset extremes (via `setExtremes()`).

Comment: It works, when I am clicking on "reset zoom" before clicking on a specific range, but is it possible to use the range selector and zoom xy together?

Comment: For sure you can edit sources. However, I think it would be easier to create your own buttons and add that setting/resetting zoom.

Comment: is there no way to call setExtremes() after selecting a range?

Comment: You can try to use `afterSetExtremes` event handler, but this is called every time even when panning or using navigator.